# Css - invisible margin during horizontal alignment in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, alignment

I would like to align six spans horizontally. I'm using Wordpress to create the page. This is the code: (you can find the Css in the jsFiddle link at the bottom of the question)

**HTML**

```
<span class="sixth">
   <a href="">
      <div class="viewProf view-first">
         <img alt="" src="" />
         <div class="maskProf">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>Role</p>
         </div>
      </div>
  </a>
</span>
<span class="sixth">
   <a href="">
      <div class="viewProf view-first">
         <img alt="" src="" />
         <div class="maskProf">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>Role</p>
         </div>
      </div>
  </a>
</span>
[...]
<span class="sixth">
   <a href="">
      <div class="viewProf view-first">
         <img alt="" src="" />
         <div class="maskProf">
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <p>Role</p>
         </div>
      </div>
  </a>
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.sixth {
  width: 13.6%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.viewProf {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  border: 3px solid #780b07;
  border-radius: 7px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px #444;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.viewProf .maskProf,
.viewProf .contentProf {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}
.viewProf img {
  display: block;
  position: relative
}
.viewProf h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 11px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  margin: 20px 0 0 0
}
.viewProf p {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 25px 25px;
  text-align: center
}
.viewProf a.info {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 7px 14px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000
}
.viewI a.info:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000
}
.view-first .maskProf {
  -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(219, 127, 8, 0.7);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.view-first h2 {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-100px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-100px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100px);
  transform: translateY(-100px);
  -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.view-first p {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(100px);
  -o-transform: translateY(100px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(100px);
  transform: translateY(100px);
  -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.view-first:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}
.view-first a.info {
  -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.view-first:hover .maskProf {
  -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
.view-first:hover h2,
.view-first:hover p,
.view-first:hover a.info {
  -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  -o-transform: translateY(0px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
.view-first:hover p {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  -ms-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.view-first:hover a.info {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -ms-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

How to remove the space at the bottom of the first span?

**EDIT**

The code in the jsFiddle works but the result in wordpress doesn't. I have tried with different browsers and I got the same problem. What could it be?

http://jsfiddle.net/userK/9zodn23h/

Comment: Add the code you tried.. without seeing it I would recommend you put all the spans inside a div and use a clearfix on that div, then float all the spans left.

Comment: Also putting a div (block element) inside an inline element (a element) isn't typically a good thing.

Comment: Could you specify what you suggested?

Comment: @narutov6: 1. Post your CSS code so we know what you tried. 2. Putting `div`s inside `spans` isn't good, because you shouldn't put a block element inside an inline one. Change the `span`s to `div`s.

Comment: Can you please create a jsFiddle?

Comment: This is amazing. In the Fiddle it works... I think it's beacause of wordpress

Comment: You most likely have another css rule somwhere interfering with the first box design. I'd recommend opening up developer tools and try to figure out what style is making the box appear like this.

Comment: Ok I will create new rules in order to avoid interferences

Comment: I changed the shortcode I was using to specify a row with a new CSS rule (width: 100%) . But notihing changed.
I created a new row with same content and I noticed that there wasn't any margin in first span! (I used the same code, copy and paste) So I deleted the top row and restored the content. Now it's fine. Clearly the Wordpress code editor had a hand in it. What answer should I write?

Answer (score 2):

As requested to specify:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mptpL5mx/2/

You want to use a clearfix (div that can wrap your floated items and allow them to work properly without breaking outside of itself)

Then you will want to float your items so they line up nicely.

Also clean up your markup (no block level items inside inline items)

HTML:

```
<div class="holder clearfix">
    <span class="sixth">
        <div class="viewProf view-first">
            <a href=""><img alt="" src="" /></a>
        </div>
    </span>
    <span class="sixth">
        <div class="viewProf view-first">
            <a href=""><img alt="" src="" /></a>
        </div>
    </span>
    <span class="sixth">
        <div class="viewProf view-first">
            <a href=""><img alt="" src="" /></a>
        </div>
    </span>
    <span class="sixth">
        <div class="viewProf view-first">
            <a href=""><img alt="" src="" /></a>
        </div>
    </span>
    <span class="sixth">
        <div class="viewProf view-first">
            <a href=""><img alt="" src="" /></a>
        </div>
    </span>
    <span class="sixth">
        <div class="viewProf view-first">
            <a href=""><img alt="" src="" /></a>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {content: ""; display: table;} 
.clearfix:after {clear: both;}
.clearfix {zoom: 1;}

.holder{
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 10px;
}

.sixth{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Comment: I changed the Css, now I have a column. Let me update the question. I need to specify that Wordpress had a hand in it. No doubt